# context.drawWindow in chrome equivalent

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, canvas, google-chrome-extension, html5-canvas

I know that only firefox extended the canvas object to include the context.drawWindow method, is there any known procedure for accomplishing what this method does in chrome?

Answer (score 0):

You can use svg to render DOM inside Canvas by creating a foreignObject containing your HTML.

Here is a library that do the work for you :

http://pbakaus.github.com/domvas/

Comment: I'm sure this is the closest without trawling API's, but it's really not good enough for most people to use.

Comment: Yes, DOMVAS does not allow to render images in the dom element